# Inconsistent solution with Index Calculus algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, cryptography

The index calculus algorithm can be used for computing discrete logarithms.
The basic idea is that you search for a set of linear independent vectors.
When you solve the corresponding matrix, you find the solutions for the discrete log problem of all the prime factors in your factor base. These can be used to solve the original discrete log problem.

I decided to make an implementation of it just for fun.
However, when solving the corresponding matrix, I sometimes run into solutions for the factors that are incorrect.
Let me show an example. Assume we have generator $g = 5$ and $h=543$ with $p = 2003$. Using the factor base $\mathcal{F} = \{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$, we want to find a solution for $$g^x \equiv h \mod(p)$$

Lets say we find the following relations which are $\mathcal{F}$-smooth:
\begin{align*}
5^{790} &= 3^2 \cdot 11^2 \\
5^{729} &= 2^5 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \\
5^{1162} &= 3^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \\
5^{919} &= 2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7^2 \\
5^{150} &= 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \\
5^{953} &= 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13
\end{align*}

This leaves us with the following matrix:
$M = $
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 790\\
5 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 729\\
0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1162\\
2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 919\\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 150\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 953
\end{pmatrix}

Using Gauss-Jordan Eliminiation, we get the following solutions:
\begin{align}
\log_5(2) &= -93 \equiv 1909 \mod(2002)\\
\log_5(3) &= 60 \\
\log_5(5) &= 859 \\
\log_5(7) &= 123 \\
\log_5(11) &= 335 \\
\log_5(13) &= 64 
\end{align}
We can check the only the $\log_5(7)$ is correct.
My question is: how is it possible that the solutions for the factors in the factor base are (mostly) incorrect, although the relations we found are linear independent?

**Edit:**

I also posted this question on Crypo Stack Exchange, which received an answer that helped me solving the problem. The link is [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41825/incorrect-solution-for-discrete-log-problem-when-using-the-index-calculus-algori/41849#41849).

Comment: the solutions that are not correct for the discrete log problem are correct for some other kind of problem. To me, it means that there are many problems that can be put in this form but the solutions are not general enough to apply to every single problem that can be put into this form.

Comment: @user25406 I'm not really sure what you mean. 
I read some [lecture notes](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~csaha/lectures/lec21.pdf) that explains the algorithm in more detail. 
I don't see anything in this paper that explains the problem I'm facing. 
I do however know that the solutions for the discrete log problems for the factors in the factor base have to be correct 
in order for the solution of the original discrete log problem to be correct.

Comment: I noticed this is the same question as asked on Crypto.SE, you may want to link them together to avoid duplicate effort.